# Accessing rootScope variable in template view not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webview, angularjs-rootscope

I know this is possible and have seen many threads on how to do this but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  My `$rootScope` variable is not appearing in my template view.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$state,$rootScope,$q,apiService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $rootScope.test = "HELLO ALL" ;

 ...
 ...
}),

.controller('EventCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$state,$stateParams) {

}),
```

And in my EventCtrl webview template:

```
<div style="color:red;font-weight:bolder;">{{$root.test}}</div>
```

Yet, `HELLO ALL` never appears.  I have tried simply `{{test}}` as suggested in some other posts but that too is not working.  What am I getting wrong here?  No errors are being generated in console.

I also tried the following, in my EventCtrl controller I set:

```
$scope.globalScope = $rootScope ;
```

And then in template accessed:  `{{globalScope.test}}` - and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `{{ test }}`, since `$scope` inherits from `$rootScope`

Check below:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test = "Hello All"
  })
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope) {})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div style="color:red;font-weight:bolder;">{{test}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marking your response as correct.  However, I was doing it right all along, however, I had added the code to an old app file and not the current one.  So everytime I was compiling the current version it was being compiled with the new code.  SUE me!

Comment: :) Happens sometimes